# Webform Content with admin approval

Tags: nodes, webforms

Hi I have a webform which user will fill and get a confirmation link.On clicking the confirmation link the user is a confirmed user.I want an add on functionality of admin approval in it so that after the admin approval the approved user name is displayed in a list.Any help please.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

There is a module for that. Check [Webform Confirmation](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_confirmation).

> This is confirmation module. It sends an e-mail to users who submit the webform for verification by taking the email id from the webform.
>
> On clicking on the confirmation link in the email, the user confirms that he/she is not a spammer. It works both for both Authenticated and Anonymous users.
>
> Also, the administrator is able to keep a track of users who have confirmed their submissions.
>
> Optionally, you can disable sending the confirmation link in the mail which would only send a "thank you" mail.

Comment: I am using this module for confirmation.I want the last part of functionality i.e. admin should approve and the name should be displayed in a list.How to get this approval thing.

Comment: @SurabhiMahindra This sounds like a new feature for the same module. Creating a "feature request" issue in the module's issue queue could take this further. I also happen to know the module maintainer and I could get your request through.

Comment: Is there any way to achieve this? I can see 3 options like confirmed,unconfirmed and all but there is no option of approval.

Comment: Yes, there is a way to achieve this :) Create an issue in the issue queue with what is it you want to achieve : https://www.drupal.org/node/add/project-issue/webform_confirmation

Comment: I have done dis.It may take time.I want the functionality part.Is there any way to achieve?

Comment: @SurabhiMahindra: I have seen your feature request. I would be working on your feature request. Most probably by EOD I would be releasing a new release having this as a new feature in Webform Confirmation module.

Comment: Hey Nitesh..I dont see any kindof updates in webform confirmation...:/

Comment: I am looking for 2 level confirmation. In this 1st level confirmation is from user side which is already working. The 2 nd level of confirmation should be through admin. This can potentially happen if request is shown as list on Result page under admin login. Once he gets list of users we can have checkbox against each row. This will help admin to update checkbox and submit his confirmation. When we see complete list we can show two columns under list (User confirmed and Admin confirmed).